# How to make retry connecting through another proxy using python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, socks

Im using requests.post with random proxies like this:

```
url = "http://localhost"
socks = "{ "http": "random_socks()" }"
payload = { "status" : "1" }
headers = { "user-agent" : "useragent"}

post = requests.post(url, payload=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, proxies=socks)

print post.text
```

I need to use post with random socks and retry it if there is some proxy related error, until it will be completed.

As I understand: need to loop event with post, check if there is timeout or other proxy error and retry post until it will be complete.
How I can do it?

Comment: I need to do it without using multiple proxies in socks variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without any checking:

```
retries = 5
post = None
for i in range(retries):
    try:
        post = requests.post(url, payload=json.dumps(payload), 
                             headers=headers, proxies=socks)
        print(post.text)
        break
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(xxx)
else:
    print('no fetch')
```

this should do it, but I'm not sure what socks = `"{ "http": "random_socks()" }"` should mean I guess that `random_socks()` is a function so the call should be different

```
post = requests.post(url, payload=json.dumps(payload), 
                     headers=headers, proxies={"http": random_socks()})
```

`random_socks()` should return 1 http proxy not a list. It should be called  in the loop so the proxy would be refetched all the time..

If I wanted to know is actually happening I would have a list of those socks proxies and I would loop over them i could log which one i'm using

```
for each_proxy in list_of_proxies:
    try:
        post = requests.post(url, payload=json.dumps(payload), 
                             headers=headers, proxies={'http':each_proxy } )
        print(post.print)
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
else:
    print('no data')
```

Answer (score 1):

You understand right, check errors in `requests.post` and then retry with an another proxy if there is a proxy error. For example use recursion:

```
from requests.exceptions import ProxyError

def post_proxy(url, payload, headers):
    try:
        post = requests.post(url, payload=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, 
                             proxies={"http": random_socks()})
        return post.text
    except ProxyError:
        return post_proxy(url, payload, headers)

url = "http://localhost"
payload = {"status": "1"}
headers = {"user-agent": "useragent"}
print post_proxy(url, payload, headers)
```